# Cómo logro que el elemento título cambie en el componente htlm cuando lo modifico en el componente ts en Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Soy absolutamente nuevo en programación y en Angular y estoy empezando a hacer una app. Quiero cambiar el título del header mediante el componente ts y no puedo. Hice lo que se ve en las imágenes pero, qué me faltó hacer? Muchas gracias desde ya.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: app.component.html]

[image: app.component.ts]

[image: app.module.ts]

Comment: El código a simple vista lo veo bien. Lo que yo verificaría es que se esté llamando al HeaderComponent en el AppComponent y que estén importados en el app.module.ts.

Comment: así tengo configurado el app component y el app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Debes incluir la etiquetas:
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
debajo de `<app-header></app-header>`
Router Outlet sirve para mostrar los componentes hijos de un componente.

Comment: si no esta manejando rutas, no es necesario agregar eso

Comment: Para que carajo, si el no esta manejando rutas en su aplicación

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente está todo bien, lo único que veo que podría afectar es que no has guardado los cambios en el app.modules.ts según lo que veo en las imágenes. Prueba a ver si es eso. Saludos